# Exception Type: MissingSchema / beautifulsoup

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I'm exploring beautifulsoup en django and it worked fine until I added a variable as url (from a model textfield with URLValidator)

I added an 'https://"+ before the model_url, but this gave also an error. what could be the problem? I googled a lot, but nothing worked.. hopefully it's not a double question.. thanks in advance!

This is my model.py

```
class ScrapeUrl(models.Model):
product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
product_ean = models.CharField(max_length=25)
scrape_url = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()])
shop_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

def __str__(self):
    return self.product_title

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.product_title) or u''
```

this is my views.py

```
def scrape_list_view(request):

model_url = ScrapeUrl.scrape_url

response = requests.get(model_url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

price = soup.find("span", {"class": "promo-price"}).text

price_dot = price.replace(",",".").replace('-','0')
price_break = price_dot.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' ','')
price_data = float(price_break)

return render(request, 'scrape_list.html', {'price_data': price_data})
```

and this is the traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/app/

Django Version: 1.11.13
Python Version: 2.7.14
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mathfilters',
 'scrapeapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/scrapeapp/views.py" in scrape_list_view
  18.   response = requests.get(good_url)

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py" in get
  72.     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py" in request
  58.         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in request
  494.         prep = self.prepare_request(req)

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in prepare_request
  437.             hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py" in prepare
  305.         self.prepare_url(url, params)

File "/Users/sanderhegeman/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py" in prepare_url
  379.             raise MissingSchema(error)

Exception Type: MissingSchema at /app/
Exception Value: Invalid URL '<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10378b050>': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10378b050>?
```

Comment: What do you expect `model_url = ScrapeUrl.scrape_url` to do? Maybe you are trying to do `model_url = ScrapeUrl.objects.get(pk=1)` or something similar? See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to retrieve `ScrapeUrl.scrape_url`. This is not a string, it's an attribute of your Django model. When you pass this to `requests.get`, it converts it to string representation what is something like

`'<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10378b050>'`

This is obviously not a valid url, so that's why you get that exception. You probably want to retrieve an object from the database, based on query parameters or the url path. To do that you can do something like

```
model_url = ScrapeUrl.objects.get(pk=int(request.query_params['id'])).scrape_url
```

Note this may still fail, if the query parameter is not present or it's not a integer or the corresponding object is not in the database.